# umbraco checkboxlist data type not saving values to xml

Tags: xslt, umbraco, checkboxlist, string, empty-list

I have umbraco data type defined as Checkbox List with several values. Let's call it Services

I go to a page and tick some values then save the page. It works fine (when I come back to the page the values are well there).

However in the contentXml table when I look into the page xml the property Services which should hold the values is empty!
When I xslt for Services value it comes as empty as well.

How do I retrieve these values and where are they stored in the database?

Thanks

PS. I have umbraco version 6.0.2.

Comment: @lucuma and? how does it relate to my question?

Comment: @lucuma I wasn't aware I should reward answers. Got it now. Besides I often give solution to my own questions as nobody replies :( or I had not yet time to check if the answers work for me.

Comment: @lucuma you were supposed to remove your comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upgraded umbraco to version 6.0.7 and now saving and displaying checkbox list values works well. Looks like there was a problem with version 6.0.2